How to deploy Angular and .Net Core containers in server that enables to access the web application via HTTPS
I have two containers, one is backend developed in .Net Core and another one is frontend developed in Angular and using Nginx to forward. Currently they are well deployed and can be accessed via HTTP. Now I have the requirement to set access via HTTPS. So I changed some files.
Dockerfile .Net Core
# Get Base .NET Core SDK Image from Microsoft
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /source

# Copy the CSPROJ file and restore and dependencies
COPY *.sln .
COPY IQC_Database_Management_API/*.csproj ./IQC_Database_Management_API/
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy the project files and build release
COPY IQC_Database_Management_API/. ./IQC_Database_Management_API/
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Generate runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
WORKDIR /source
EXPOSE 5001
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5001
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
COPY --from=build-env /source/out .
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet","IQC_Database_Management_API.dll" ]

Dockerfile frontend:
# Stage 1: Build the Angular application
FROM node:latest AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build --prod

# Stage 2: Serve the application with Nginx
FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=build /app/dist/ESI_IQCDatabase /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

nginx.conf:
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass   https://iqc-api-container2:5001/api/;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}

launchSettings.json in .Net Core:
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5069"
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7213;http://localhost:5069"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Docker"
      },
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true,
      "httpPort": 5000,
      "sslPort": 5001
    }
  },
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:56246",
      "sslPort": 44369
    }
  }
}

When I try docker run in the remote server, the container fails to launch. The command I used is sudo docker run -d -v /home/qq/IQC_Database.db:/source/IQC_Database.db -p 7213:5001 --name iqc-api-container2 iqc-api2
Could someone help point out where I did wrong?
Update:
I have changed the nginx.conf to:
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name azeu1-eng-leon1.company.com;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}

And run the command openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout certs/server.key -out certs/server.crt -subj "/CN=azeu1-eng-leon1.company.com and move the server.crt and server.keys to the containers /etc/nginx/certs folder. Then I restart the container but still I cannot access to the page VIA HTTPS.

A common way to do this is to access Nginx using HTTPS and then terminate HTTPS at that stage and use HTTP from Nginx to the API container. That way your frontend will also be served using HTTPS. The Nginx container will also be the only container you have to configure with certificates, etc.

@HansKilian That also comes to my mind. What confuses me is, the two containers communicate with each other via a bridge network that I created. Can I just deploy the frontend container(including Nginx) via HTTPS and deploy the backend container as usual.

Yes, that's what I would do. If the API container port isn't mapped to a host port, it isn't available from outside the bridge network. All traffic to the API container would come through the Nginx container and would be HTTPS to and from the clients. And, as you say, you can deploy the API container without any changes from what you have now.

@HansKilian I have updated the nginx.conf but still I cannot visit the frontend page.

How do you run the container? Remember to map a host port to port 443 in the container.

@HansKilian I run with sudo docker run -d -p 4200:443 iqc-frontend_v2. Now I can access the page. But when I want to click login button, I got 404 error. I have modified the port maping in api container to 5069:5001 where 5001 is set as sslPort.

Access to the API should be through Nginx, so you should keep the proxy_pass block from your original nginx config, except it should use HTTP. And access the API at https://localhost:4200/api. And the API container should only use HTTP. Not HTTPS.
